# "Sorry, user user1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on hostname"

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo

I ran `sudo ls` as user1 and I got this message.

```
Sorry, user user1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on hostname.
```

And this is my user1 group info and sudoers file.

```
user1@hostname:$ id
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lpadmin),111(sambashare)

user1@hostname:$ cat /etc/sudoers
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I don't know what changes I made before this problem occurred.
My system is Ubuntu 14.04.5 (DigitalOcean).

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l`, please.

Comment: @muru
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on hostname:
env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr‌​/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/‌​snap/bin User user1 may run the following commands on hostname: (ALL : ALL) ALL (root) NOPASSWD: !ALL, /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in the file `/etc/sudoers.d/user1`.

I had set user1 to execute only `sudo bash` command and forgotten about it.

Thanks [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for [suggesting the `sudo -l` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950658/cannot-run-any-commands-with-sudo/1263614#comment1514204_950658).

```
user1   ALL=NOPASSWD: !ALL, /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is a problem with your additions to /etc/sudoers or /etc/sudoers.d
If you use a command outside of files in secure_path you need to add the path (for example, /my/special/path/bin